# How to figure out the Nth node of something that I currently am in using XPATh

Tags: c#, xpath

Ok.  I have an attribute in an xml document that I know will occur more than once.  Using C# I loop through all the nodes that have this attribute.  I know how to count the occurrence of an element using xpath...

```
count("//x/y@b")
```

and so on.
But is there a way that I can get the n-th value of a node that I am on... for example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x>
   <y/>
   <y/>
   <y/>
</x>
```

Let's say I was looping through that programatically using c#.  And lets say I was on the second  element.  Is there any way using xpath that I could figure out that I am on the 2nd node?  I guess I am just trying to find my position in the iteration.  Any ideas?  Currently scouring the internet.  If I find it out I will be sure to let you know.

Thanks.

**UPDATE: CAN'T SEEM to get my stuff to work**
Ok.  I thought I would update my question.  I can't seem to get any of your suggestions working...

```
<Template>
 <TemplateData>
  <ACOData>
   <POPULATION_PATIENT_ID>6161</POPULATION_PATIENT_ID>
   <PATIENT_ID>4329</PATIENT_ID>
  </ACOData>
  <ACOData>
   <POPULATION_PATIENT_ID>5561</POPULATION_PATIENT_ID>
   <PATIENT_ID>4327</PATIENT_ID>
  </ACOData>
  <ACOData>
   <POPULATION_PATIENT_ID>6160</POPULATION_PATIENT_ID>
   <PATIENT_ID>4321</PATIENT_ID>
  </ACOData>
  <ACOData>
   <POPULATION_PATIENT_ID>5561</POPULATION_PATIENT_ID>
   <PATIENT_ID>4320</PATIENT_ID>
  </ACOData>
```

That is the XML that I am using.  But I can't seem to get the correct count.  I am always coming up with zero?

```
encounter = Int32.Parse((patElm.CreateNavigator().Evaluate("count(/Template/TemplateData/ACOData/POPULATION_PATIENT_ID[.='" + populationPatID + "']/preceding-sibling::ACOData/POPULATION_PATIENT_ID[.='"+populationPatID+"'])")).ToString());
```

The above is the code that I am attempting to use to get the correct value... Note my count function

```
count(/Template/TemplateData/ACOData/POPULATION_PATIENT_ID[.='" + populationPatID + "']/preceding-sibling::ACOData/POPULATION_PATIENT_ID[.='"+populationPatID+"'])"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the second such element in the document use:

```
(//x/y[@b])[2]
```

Suppose you want to go the other way. That is, you have one of these nodes and you want to know its overall position. In general, for any expression `<expr>` the following is true:

```
$n = count((<expr>)[$n]/preceding::*[count(.|<expr>)=count(<expr>)])
```

That is, the position of the Nth element selected by `<expr>` can be found by counting all the preceding elements also selected by that expression. Using similar techniques, we can find the position of some node that *would be selected* by a more general expression, within the set of all nodes selected by that expression.

For example, suppose we have the following document:

```
<x>
    <y b="true"/>
    <y b="true"/>
    <y/>
    <y/>
    <x><y b="true"/><y/><y b="true">77</y></x>
    <y/>
    <y/>
</x>
```

And we want to know the position in the document of the node at `/*/*/y[.='77']` among all nodes selected by `//x/y[@b]`. Then use the following expression:

```
count(/*/*/y[.='77']/preceding::*[count(.|//x/y[@b])=count(//x/y[@b])]) + 1
```

A more specific one-off solution looks like this:

```
count(/*/*/y[.='77']/preceding::y[parent::x and @b]) + 1
```

Result (in both cases):

```
4
```

**Note:** It's assumed that `/*/*/y[.='77']` and `(<expr>)[$n]` above actually select some node in the document. If not, the result will be an erroneous `1` due to adding 1 to the result of the count. For this reason, this method is probably most useful when working on a context node or when it is guaranteed that your initial expression selects a node. (Of course, initial error checking can be employed, as well.)

Comment: Good answer.  One question however just to make sure I have it.  
How would I get that value?  Would I just use XmlNode.SelectSingleNode?

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say I was looping through that programatically using c#. And
>   lets say I was on the second element. Is there any way using xpath
>   that I could figure out that I am on the 2nd node?

Suppose, as you say, that the current (initial context) node is `/x/y[2]` and you want to see what is its "position".

**Evaluate this XPath expression** (off the current node):

```
count(preceding-sibling::y) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) function

```
x/y[position() = 3]
```